# Aplicar Tema a NavigationDrawer

Tags: android

estoy creando un app que agrupa redes sociales, mi problema es que quiero que cambie el tema de la app y tambien el color de la cabecera del navigationDrawer de acuerdo al item seleccionado, por ejemplo si selecciono Facebook cambia al color del face o si selecciono instagram lo mismo
el codigo del fragment es este:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context themeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.TemaFacebook);
    inflater = inflater.cloneInContext(themeWrapper);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_bar_with_tab, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FacebookViewPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_noticias_small);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_request_friends_small);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_small);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        activity.updateView(getString(R.string.subFacebook));

    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    activity.navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_facebook);

}

private class FacebookViewPageAdapter extends BaseViewPageAdapter {

    public FacebookViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager, new String[] {"Noticias", "Solicitudes", "Notificaciones"},new Integer[] {
                R.drawable.ic_noticias,
                R.drawable.ic_request_friends,
                R.drawable.ic_notifications
        });
    }
}
```

y el MainActivity es este:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
public NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (navigationView != null)
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void updateView(String title) {

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null)
        toolbar.setSubtitle(title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toogle);
    toogle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    SubMenu sub1 = menu.addSubMenu("Version Web");

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://instagram.com"));
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://twitter.com"));
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://plus.google.com"));
    Intent intent4 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://facebook.com"));

    sub1.add(0, 3, 3, "Instagram").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_instagram).setIntent(intent);
    sub1.add(0, 5, 5, "Twitter").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_twitter).setIntent(intent2);
    sub1.add(0, 4, 4, "Google+").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_google_plus).setIntent(intent3);
    sub1.add(0, 2, 2, "Facebook").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_facebook).setIntent(intent4);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    View view = new View(getApplicationContext());

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.menu_compartir) {
        listaRedesSociales(view);
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.menu_configuracion) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Configuracion en progreso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_inicio:
            fragment = new MainFragment();

            break;
        case R.id.nav_facebook:
            fragment = new FacebookFragment();

            break;
        case R.id.nav_instagram:
            fragment = new InstagramFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_google:
            fragment = new GoogleFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_twitter:
            fragment = new TwitterFragment();
            break;

    }
    if (fragment != null)
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();


    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void listaRedesSociales(View view) {

    DialogoLista.listaCheck(this, view).show();

}
```

}

ContextThemeWrapper me cambia el theme pero no el color del navigationView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de manera rustica cambiando el color del NavigationDrawer cuando de clic en un red social utilizando

```
navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
navigationView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ejemplo);
```

Y muchas más, aplicando en tu caso sería algo como:

```
switch (id) {
    case R.id.nav_inicio:
        fragment = new MainFragment();

        break;
    case R.id.nav_facebook:

        navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(62,91,154));
        navigationView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        fragment = new FacebookFragment();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_instagram:

        navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.instagram);
        navigationView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        fragment = new InstagramFragment();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_google:
        navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.google);
        navigationView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        fragment = new GoogleFragment();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_twitter:

        navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(29,161,242));
        navigationView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        fragment = new TwitterFragment();
        break;

}
```

En este caso como ves yo utilice 2 formas por color y rgb, y también por una imagen drawable que tengas guardada, elige la que gustes, espero haber respondido lo que pedías

Comment: Excelente es lo que necesitaba, Gracias